# How do I use custom model binder that supports dependency injection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, model-binding

I am trying to use a custom model binder in MVC that I want resolved from my IoC container.  The issue I am having is that I can't access my container while I am adding the MVC service, because my container isn't built yet (and I need to add MVC before building my container).  Feels like a chicken/egg issue, and I am sure I am missing a simple solution.

Example:

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
     options.ModelBinders.Add(serviceProvider.Resolve<CustomModelBinder>());
});
```

My custom model binder looks like this:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public CustomModelBinder(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = serviceProvider.GetService(bindingContext.ModelType);
        bindingContext.Model = model;

        var binder = new GenericModelBinder();
        return binder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the post here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4167

To answer your question directly, use:

```
bindingContext.OperationBindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
```

On a side note, you also have the option of using `[FromServices]` to resolve it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core 2.2, this should work for DI:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // dependency injection
        var model = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(bindingContext.ModelType);

        // other changes...

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a service locator pattern where the required service is retrieved in the model binder you can use `IConfigureOptions` to configure options with dependency injection. This allows you to delay the configuration of options until the dependency injection container has been built.

Here is a model binder having a dependency on `ICustomService`:

```
class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly ICustomService customService;

    public CustomModelBinder(ICustomService customService) => this.customService = customService;

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Use customService during model binding.
    }
}
```

You need a provider for this model binder:

```
class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly ICustomService customService;

    public CustomModelBinderProvider(ICustomService customService) => this.customService = customService;

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        // Return CustomModelBinder or null depending on context.
        return new CustomModelBinder(customService);
    }
}
```

Normally, you would add the model binder provider in `Startup` using code like this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Add(new CustomModelBinderProvider(customService));
});
```

However, as you have noted this is not possible. You cannot resolve `customService` while the system is being configured. The general solution to this problem is to use `IConfigureOptions` with the above code to configure the options but with the added benefit of being able to use dependency injection:

```
class CustomModelBinderConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly ICustomService customService;

    public CustomModelBinderConfigureMvcOptions(ICustomService customService) => this.customService = customService;

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
        => options.ModelBinderProviders.Add(new CustomModelBinderProvider(customService));
}
```

This class has to be added to the container in `Startup`

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, CustomModelBinderConfigureMvcOptions>();
```

You are now able to use a model binder with a dependency.

Comment: I am getting error on CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(), Unable to resolve service for type 'IMyinterface' while attempting to activate 'CustomModelBinderConfigureMvcOptions'.